# Data range filters in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I want to allow the user to be able to define ranges that will filter data. The ranges defined could be contiguous, over lapping, or separated (e.g. the user enters the following ranges: 1-10, 5-10, 10-12, 7-13, and 15-20).

I then want to filter the data so that the user is only displayed what is within those ranges.

I will probably create code on a different layer that will combine the ranges where appropriate (so the above example will become 1-13 and 15-20, but I don't want my data service to be concerned with that, so it must be able to handle the example above)

I have a lot of data and speed is a priority, so I don't want to have to iterate through a list of ranges for each data item to check if it should be displayed to the user or not.

Is there a data structure (or some algorithm) that could be used to achieve this?

Comment: Wouldn't make combining the ranges make sense in the filter? It would also simplify the task.

Comment: I was more interested in seeing if there was a solution that didn't require combining them at all. If all reasonable solutions require there only be the separated ranges then I will do this processing as soon as the user enters the data before the data service ever has to deal with it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use boost's [filter_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html) to achieve this.

Comment: Isn't that going to just iterate over the range filters for each element until it gets a yes/no answer on it?  The OP said he wanted to avoid that for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If you sort your list of ranges, you can then use binary search to minimize iteration.  But really, unless you have an large number of ranges, iteration will be fastest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iterators into your containers. For example, std::vector provides the "at" method.  These iterators can be contiguous, overlapping, or separated.

Answer (score 0):

Make your list disjoint (as you suggested), combining ranges which overlap. Then sort the array of endpoints, and for each data element, do a binary search and determine whether it's within a range or outside it. Even elements will always begin a range, odd elements will always end a range.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in general depends on range bounds.

1. If `max`-`min` is not so huge (for example, you define bounds in [1..1024]), you could use just an array, which point every X to the list of ranges. For your example, the array should be:

```
ranges=[0:(1,10), 1:(5,10), 2:(10,12), 3:(7,13), 4:(15-20)]
points=[1:[0],2:[0],3:[0],4:[0],5:[0,1],...,7:[0,1,3],...10:[0,1,2,3],...15:[4],...20:[4],21:[]...]
```

So, in this case you could quicly determine the ranges for particular X.

2. You could use [Interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) - less efficient, but memory frendlier (of course more efficient than brute-force solution)

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to combine ranges you receive and map them to an underlying bitmap indicating *in* or *not in* the range.

A class-based design would allow you to overload `operator +=` for syntactic sugar, but a bare bitmap would work just as well. For instance:

```
# original bitmap
bits = [ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 ]

# add 1-5
bits = [ 0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0 ]

# add 4 - 6
bits = [ 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0 ]

# Look for 3
bits[3] == 1 ?
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is known as [Range Minimum Query](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_Minimum_Query).

Answer (score 0):

It's not too hard if your data is allready sorted. Use a combination of

- [lower bound](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/non_mutating/lower_bound.html)
- [upper bound](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/non_mutating/upper_bound.html)

For each of your subranges [min, max] you can find the iterators i_min and i_max and 
use them as

```
std::make_pair(i_min, i_max)
```

to make it "range" compatible. Then use boost::join to concatenate all the sub
ranges into a single range ( lazily of course ) and then use this range in down
stream processing.

Obviously you should pre-process all your ranges to make sure they are non overlapping.